# how to name the text field generated by jquery for php $_POST to fetch variables

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jquery form spinner script that generates text fields based on user input and it's working fine. But i need to figure out how to name these fields so I can fetch the variable values with php $_POST..

Pls Note: There are five input text fields generated per row depending on whatever number entered by the user and these fields are name, phone, email, sex and position. 
Below are names I like to give each input field:

```
cand_name, cand_phone, cand_email, cand_sex, cand_pos
```

Pls find the jquery form spinner script at the link below

http://o2decor.com/form_scripts/jquery.fspin.js

Below is a link to the html

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Form Spinner Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fspin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                //you have to use the ID not the name of the fields we're interested in
                jQ_Form_Spinner('#container','#myrel',jQ_Form_Spinner_data);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

<body>


<form action="course_reg.php" method="post">
<p>
<label><strong>No of Candidates</strong></label>
<label><input type="text" id="myrel" name="cand_no" placeholder="Type Your Number of Candidates" /></label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</p>

<div style="width:660px; float: left; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:3px 3px;" id='container'>

</div>


</form>
```

Below is the link to view the form page running the jscript (it's working perfectly)

http://o2decor.com/form_scripts/form.php

Sorry I could not paste the jquery codes here, stackoverflow would not accept my question cos i didnt format the code well or something... Would appreciate if anyone can help out with this problem...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4BEe7/)**.

The JavaScript below (**form.php**) renames the fields when the form is submitted with the following naming convention: `candidate[X][Y]` — where **X** is the row number and **Y** is the field name.

So, for example, the **phone** field in the first row will be named `candidate[0][phone]` and the **email** field in the second row will be named `candidate[1][email]`.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var fields = ['name', 'phone', 'email', 'sex', 'pos'];
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        $('#container tbody tr').each(function(i){
            $(this).find('td').each(function(j){
                var field = fields[j];
                $(this).find(':input').attr('name', 'candidate[' + i + '][' + field + ']');
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

What you get on the PHP-side (**course_reg.php**) is a single variable (`$_POST['candidate']`) that contains all the data in a structured format as a multi-dimensional array.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Jane Doe"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "123-555-4567"
    ["email"]=>
    string(18) "jane.doe@email.add"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(6) "female"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(3) "CEO"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(12) "234-555-6789"
    ["email"]=>
    string(18) "john.doe@email.add"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(4) "male"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(3) "CTO"
  }
}
```

What the populated form looked like with the above data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/peA63.gif

You can read-in this data using the PHP below.
(Note: This is just a demo. I'm leaving the security stuff up to you.)

```
<?php

$candidates = array();

foreach ($_POST['candidate'] as $i => $can)
{
    $candidates[$i] = array();

    foreach ($can as $key => $value)
    {
        $candidates[$i][$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($candidates);
```

Of course, `var_dump($candidates)` will produce the exact same output as `var_dump($_POST['candidate'])`, since we're maintaining the same structure.

How you want to structure the data is up to you.

*Update:*

I created this ZIP archive that contains **form.php** and **course_reg.php**: **[[Download]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wz6ngmwuhtz3jd/so1.zip)**

1. Upload the two files on to your server.
2. Access **form.php** through your web browser.
3. Populate the form.
4. Hit the "Submit" button.
5. **course_reg.php** should now display the populated data.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond earlier...Thanks for your help, I'm very grateful. But I'm stil unable to fetch the form data with the 'candidate' array. It looks to me like the 'candidate' array does not exist or $_POST cant find or connect it... I understand I would be asking for too much considering what you done above but it would really help if you could run the script you have in the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/4BEe7/) by entering some test data (John Doe), submit and fetch those data using php and then print or echo the form data right there...Once again, thanks for your help...

Comment: @user1630911 I've updated my answer (towards the bottom) with a download link. Please have a look and get back to me.

Comment: @Coby...U'r the man! Thanks a trillion...U did great...Thanks...Just thinking of how to show my gratitude...Do u have a project site where I can make a little donation? or we could talk about this better in private if you don't mind...You could send me an email, My yahoo id is odelesamson 'at' yahoo.com...My skype name is "sam_odele"...Hope to read from you...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SO the problem you have is you have dynamic amount of phone numbers, for example and you want to capture all of them in a post. but the problem is they all have the same name.

```
name="phone_number";
```

so you could pass it as an array

```
name="phone_number[]"
```

then loop through it in the php submit page.

am I correct?

Comment: Yea i know i have to use a for loop to insert the value into the DB. But before running a loop, I need the names of those input fields and then use $_POST to capture them. The problem I'm having is how to name those input fields from the jquery script (jquery.fspin.js)...I can't name these input fields within HTML and it's difficult capturing those fields within the php submit script bcos these input fields are being generated from inside the jquery script above....I'm not good with jquery and I hope you would be able to help out with this...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the jQ_Form_Spinner plugin which you are using sucks :)

Look at the name and id attributes that it creates for each form element:

```
<input type="text" name="textfield_0" id="textfield_0" placeholder="Enter your full name" style="margin-right: 12px;" class="">
```

The configuration doesn't even let you change those names to anything else. Based on that, you're going to have a hard time getting this to work.

You would need to modify the plugin such that the `jQ_Form_Spinner_getField` function creates reasonable name and id attributes for each form element.

My advice is to get rid of the jQ_Form_Spinner plugin. You don't need it. What you are trying to do (dynamically create a form) is trivial when writing Javascript/jQuery code by hand. If you're only learning to code, then this would be a good task to start off with.

Give it a go, and ask some more questions if you get stuck.